Is there any way to refactor NextJS global import in VSCode?
I am working in a NextJS project, recently switched from WebStorm to VSCode.
If I have a file called nav-bar.tsx, whenever I hit F2 to rename it to navbar.tsx, in the files that import this navbar, only relative import like ./nav-bar gets updated to ./navbar, but global import like @/components/nav-bar will remain in error.
It is common for me to do refactoring like this. What do I do?

Also wondering about this!
